# What is the purpose of RakeFile in the application root directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby on Rails and I see a 'Rakefile' in my application's root directory. What is its purpose and when will it get executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Rakefile` is a ruby-written file which contains the definition of [Rake tasks](http://rake.rubyforge.org/).
[Here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html) you can find a small introduction to Rake.

The `Rakefile` can include other Ruby files. This is the case of Rails projects.
In fact, in a Rails project you shouldn't change the Rakefile directly. Instead, you can add more rake tasks by creating .rake files in the `lib/tasks` folder of your Rails project.

Answer (score 3):

It contains several pre-defined actions (named tasks) that you could perform on the Rails project. If you run `rake -T`, it will show you a list of all available tasks. That will provide you with more info.